# Migration from Cloudera to Hortonworks

Tags: cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, bigdata

Our client is planning to migrate hadoop environment from Cloudera to HortonWorks because of some reason.

Can someone please provide me if there is any standard document available which specifies the steps need to be taken care for this kind of migration?

In other work can we use `hadoop distcp` command to copy hdfs data from Cloudera environment to Hortonworks.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can use distcp.**

You can also do the migration in place depending on the version of CDH you are migrating from and version of HDP you are migrating too. It will also depend on the services you are using in hadoop, and the versions of those schemas. For example, if you are using version X.3 of Hive in Cloudera and you are migrating to X.2 in Hortonworks, there will be issues with the schemas. It seems really risky and messy to migrate in place, although in theory doable.

**I'd recommend going the distcp route**, that way you can validate the data in your new Hortonworks cluster against the Cloudera cluster before decommissioning it.